Sonarqube not including files in subdirs
I have a project, a mulesoft project, that has *.xml  files in various directories and subdirectories.
Ik looks like this:
- pom.xml
|-subdir
|-subdir2
     |-file.xml
     |-file2.xml
     subsubdir
         |-file3.xml

the sonarqube project settings have *.xml  and  pom.xml  and even \subdir2\file.xml  in the INCLUDED list.
Strangely, only the pom.xml is included, according to the logging. And in the analysis results, only the pom.xml is reported.
Why aren't the other xml's scanned?

To clarify further: i have a Sonarqube plugin that will scan the Mulesoft code. This plugin however has nothing to do, because it does not get files presented by Sonarqube. I assume the problem is with the fact that Sonarqube does not recursively scan the project directory and hence does not find the (xml) files.

Please share your config

what exactly do you need? the sonarqube config or of only this mule project? (pom.xml) ?

The sonar config

The problem is in the fact that the Mule project is a non-Maven project and hence is unable to be scanned.
This article is describing the fix:
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-analyze-all-the-xml-files-in-a-project/8979/2
